# Unable to setup web.py on apache2 using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, web.py

Here are my config files, 
/etc/apach2/sites-availabled/currentcost

```
<VirtualHost *:20108>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
WSGIScriptAlias /currentcost /var/www/currentcost/server.py
AddType text/html .py

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

I reload apache and restart it. I am trying to access it with http://{BASE URL}:20108/

It is not accessible. 
Can anyone help me out?

I have followed steps given in http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache

My ENV :

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/2.8 Python/2.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: 1) Shouldn't you be trying to access it at http://{BASE URL}:20108/currentcost 
2) Isn't it bad form to put your python code underneath document root (that might be django recommendation but it would seem to be applicable here... the idea being that if something goes wrong, someone may be able to view your python source files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set ServerName for the VirtualHost. If you have other virtual hosts on the same server, Apache will not know how to route to this virtual host without it.

Also, have you added the appropriate NameVirtualHost directive for port 20108?